# Evaluating over individual regions present in a shapefile

Tags: shapefile, google-earth-engine

I have a shapefile with 90 different regions. I have evaluated first day of snow for all these values together after importing this asset. Now I want the value for each region individually. How can I use one row from the asset table and evaluate the code over it, and then loop it for all 90 rows? Using Google Earth Engine, JavaScript.

Comment: Have you seen the [reduceRegions](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/reducers_reduce_regions) method?

Comment: @Matt hey thanks, gotta try this out. I'm kinda confused though if this would provide me with values for all the rows individually

Comment: My apologies, I initially misinterpreted your question, thinking you wanted to sample a raster. But as I understand it, you just want to extract the values from your imported shapefile. I have added a small example as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This code snippet finds the majority Corine land cover for 3 arbitrary polygons drawn in France and outputs them to an array. I think the [aggregateArray()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-featurecollection-aggregate_array) method at the end is what you are after to get your snow value per table row.

```js
var collection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/CORINE/V20/100m")
var image = collection.first()

// reduce regions to a feature collection
var majority_value_per_poly = image.reduceRegions({
  collection: polys,   // a shapefile of polygons ingested as asset
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mode(), // use mode to find the majority land cover per region (polygon)
  scale:30  // target pixel size
})

// get value per polygon from feature collection, where "mode" is the column name
var column_values = majority_value_per_poly.aggregate_array("mode")
print(column_values)

// outputs [210,211,211]
```